# Cannot get JSON file from Server using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a request via AJAX with a user selected stop number to a Bus Stop Arrival time API url that returns a *.json file to me that I need to be able to utilize in my code.   When I run the program it hits the 'Error' in my getJSON function.  When I look at fiddler or even in debug via browsers I can see that it's returning the array I want to use.  In, I.E. or Firefox, I can look at the Response/Response Body and see the array in there.  Not sure where or why I can't get it working so I'm turning to you all, the experts.  Please let me know what else I can try and provide.

Using this library:

```html
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

```
// Returns the next 4 bus arrival times  
function getTimes(stopNumber) {

var busArrivalAPI = "http://cfsrv1/api/index.cfm/rtcTimes/"+ stopNumber;

function getJSON() {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: busArrivalAPI,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",          
    success: function(data) {
      busArrival = $.parseJSON(data);
      // This will remove old values so table will only load current Times
      var results = document.getElementById("results");
      var rowCount = results.rows.length;
      for (var x=rowCount-1; x>0; x--) {
        results.deleteRow(x);
      }

      //  This will populate the result table with the correct bus routes/times/direction
      data.forEach(function(busArrival) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var route = document.createElement('td');
        route.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.ROUTE));
        var arrival = document.createElement('td');
        arrival.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.ARRIVAL));
        var direction = document.createElement('td');
        direction.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.DIR));
        tr.appendChild(route);
        tr.appendChild(arrival);
        tr.appendChild(direction);
        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(tr);
      });
    },
    error: function() {
      alert(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
getJSON();
}
```

Raw Data from Fiddler Web Debugger (I'm only in need of the ROUTE, ARRIVAL, and DIR):

```
GET http://cfsrv1/api/index.cfm/rtcTimes/2935?   callback=jQuery111206901489450284122_1422567353037&_=1422567353038 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8020/RTCSystemMap/index.html
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like     Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: cfsrv1
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 29 Jan 2015 21:35:58 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-RTCTimes-HEADER: RTCSNV Times
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ALLOW: GET

[{"ARRIVAL":"01:44P","DEV":"   0","ROUTE":"104","DIR":"N","TRIPID":"357498261"},
{"ARRIVAL":"02:14P","DEV":"  10","ROUTE":"104","DIR":"N","TRIPID":"357498262"},
{"ARRIVAL":"02:44P","DEV":"   1","ROUTE":"104","DIR":"N","TRIPID":"357498263"},
{"ARRIVAL":"03:14P","DEV":"   0","ROUTE":"104","DIR":"N","TRIPID":"357498264"}]
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Bus Arrival Times', selected:true">
  <table id='results'>
    <tr>
      <th><b>Route</b>
      </th>
      <th><b>Arrival Time</b>
      </th>
      <th><b>Direction</b>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `alert('Error')` try to log the actual error message you get: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { console.log( errorThrown ); }` It's likely that it's a cross-domain restriction but hard to say for sure without extra details.

Comment: Here is the error that it gives me.  Had that in there before for testing and spaced putting it back.        Error: jQuery111208398147836967592_1422568311175 was not called

Comment: That means the server doesn't return valid JSONP.

Comment: The server returns a *.json file so should I be using the dataType: "json" instead?  because I tried that and it gives me a error saying Access is denied when using I.E. and with firefox in debug says: 405 Method Not Allowed. (Reload the page to get source for: http://cfsrv1/api/index.cfm/rtcTimes/3392).  However I read that leaving it jsonp is the norm.

Comment: If you want a cross-domain request you'll need to either use JSONP or set the server to send proper headers, but if you want to use JSONP you'll have to send proper JSONP. You can't send plain JSON and expect that it works.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  It was on the other side.  I had to have the help of our Systems guy and he fixed a few things.  Thanks all.  CLOSED.